# Center TextView over ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview, textview, center, android-relativelayout

I have image and text that I want to put on my app.
I need the text to be centered over the image.
Everything is done programmatically with RelativeLayout Object.
For some reason, I only succeed to center the TextView over the ImageView vertically.

**This is the function that creates the RelativeLayout:**

```
 private void buildPost(Context context){

    Random rnd = new Random();
    SquareImageView postBgImgIV = new SquareImageView(context);
    postBgImgIV.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256)));
    postBgImgIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.clear);


    TextView postContentTV = new TextView(context);
    postContentTV.setText(this.postContent);
    postContentTV.setTextSize(42);
    //postContentTV.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
    postContentTV.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);


    post = new RelativeLayout(context);
    post.addView(postBgImgIV);
    post.addView(postContentTV);
}
```

I sure that I missing something and it can't solve with few lines of code.
I will love to get help :)

Comment: I think your views are lacking width and height which are mandatory, for which you would need a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. When using this class you would also have to position the image and the and the textview relative to the container (post RelativeLayout). It would a bit easier if you set all this in the xml and change it a runtime instead of creating everything dinamically.

Comment: That will be a little bit difficult since I don't have the relativeLayout at the xml.
I create the relativeLayout  'on the go' with code and then push the relativeLayout to scrollView.

Comment: You will have to do it programatically then. And the RelativeLayout, before you add it to the parent view, will also need its Layouts set, the specific class will depend on the parent. For example if it is a FrameLayout, the the RelativeLayout will need a FrameLayout.LayoutParams to be set as its layoutParams.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and now I facing an issue that I can't convert LinearLayout params (the layout that exists at the xml) to RelativeLayout params

Answer (score 2):

Problem Solved!
Actully I needed to define new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and then difiene the textView LayoutParams as the new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.

The code it:

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    postContentTV.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add layout params to the textview

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(context);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);;
```

Comment: That's not working, since that `textView.getLayoutParams()` is not defined and returns null.
The error message : `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.addRule(int)' on a null object reference`